# Read heavy query with key as range

Tags: sql, redis

I have data like,

```
Range       data
1-47        xyz
47-56       abc
57-102      eft
```

Query will be on Range, but lookup value will like 15 and should be return `1-47 xyz`. What is the way to build database(any) for performance. Data will be 20 million and read heavy 100 million read per sec. Any on suggestion key and database/datastore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your data model!  Use two columns or for the range, so you can simply do:

```
select t.*
from t
where ? between lo and hi;
```

Storing a range as a string is a really bad idea.  Storing numbers in strings in a bad idea.  Fix the data model.